# With AWS S3 MultiPart upload to a named directory using C# and the .Net SDK

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

The following fails with this error message:
"The specified upload does not exist. The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been aborted or completed."

```
UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
.WithBucketName(IniValues.Instance.TargetBucketName)
.WithKey("junk/20070125.log")
.WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
.WithPartNumber(i)
.WithPartSize(partSize)
.WithFilePosition(filePosition)
.WithFilePath("C:\\InetTemp\\Logs\\20070125.log");
```

The problem is with the ".WithKey("junk/20070125.log")". If I strip out the "junk/" it works perfectly.

So the question is, **how to upload a file to a specific AWS directory?** All the documentation I found shows tha correct way to be to prepend the directory name and a forward slash.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I was adding the folder name to the string after calling InitiateMultipartUploadRequest. Once I changed the key value to be consistent across the upload calls it began to work.